# Facebook SDK. Cannot include links when posting to my application's page

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk, access-token

I am developing a desktop application that I use to manage a variety of assets including a Facebook page.

I created a page associated with my own Facebook user.

I have generated an access token to use in my code (associated with a Facebook App that I created for this purpose).

When my application tries to post to the page, it is successful. However, If I include a link using the Link argument, the post appears in the "Recent Posts by others" list under my personal Facebook user identity.

```
string facebookAccessToken = TestApp.Properties.Settings.Default.FacebookAccessToken.ToString();

var fb = new FacebookClient(facebookAccessToken);

var argList = new Dictionary<string, object>();

argList["message"] = "Test post";

\\argList["link"] = "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/";

fb.Post("dummy.facebook.page/feed", argList);
```

I tried experimenting with the permissions when generating the access token. Even if I request all permissions, I still have the same outcome.

Perhaps it isn't possible to include links or pictures when posting via the SDK? Surely not.

Any ideas/suggestions will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to change 
`dummy.facebook.page/feed`to `dummy.facebook.page/lists`